# Meteor keys with embedded spaces

Tags: meteor

I am trying to find out how to correctly request the data for inserting into a template. I have imported an Excel spreadsheet into my Meteor Mongo instance using meteorimport and can query the data without issue. I have established a template as follows:

```
<template name="buc">
<ul>
{{#each bucs}}
    <li>
        v4ATDomainHierarchy | {{v4ATDomainHierarchy}}
        ADDIE Group | {{ADDIE Group}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

A findOne() call on the database shows the following structure.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54428261001881be69a9a492"),
"v4ATDomainHierarchy" : "1.1.1.3.6",
"System OpAct Name" : "Store All Training/Instructional Material",
"MNUC Number" : "ALCMC-3000",
"ADDIE Group" : "Develop",
"SME Team" : "A",
"BUC No." : 2.1,
"BUC OV6c Version" : "v2",
"MOE Developed" : "",
"MOP Developed" : "",
"" : ""}
```

Notice that many of the keys have spaces. My question is how to properly request the data from the key "ADDIE Group" (or any key containing a space). The error is of course that it can't find the ADDIE helper.

Thanks for any help! I have not found anything that references this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use `this` object that point to each document. So you can access it with `this["ADDIE Group"]` in template helper.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was not able to inline it directly into the template, but was able to use the this["ADDIE Group"] syntax in a helper. Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

> JS

```
Template.registerHelper("withKey", function(item){
    return this[item];
})
```

> HTML

```
{{withKey "Example Field"}}
```

> Data

```
{_id:"XXRANDOMXX", "Example Field":"Example Data"}
```

> Result

```
Example Data
```

Comment: explain your answer.